# What is a good way to classify or cluster free form text entries?

Tags: machine-learning, grouping, cluster-analysis

I have a set of ratings entered by users for N-items, along with reasons as to why they select that rating for that item. The ratings are in an ordinal scale (-2, -1, 0, +1, +2).
I would like to come up with meaningful groupings of these reasons. For example, say users are rating movies and reasons behind the ratings might fall under 3 broad groups: 1). 'They are huge fan of the actor', 2). 'Amazing Story line', 4). 'Lacks originality'. This is just a dummy example.

More concretely, given a set of free form textual entries, can one come up with such groupings. I know that topic modeling is one way of doing this. I can specify the number of topics K, and then feed data into my topic model (LDA etc.), the model will output K topics where each topic is a list of most probable words in that topic. So with respect to this dummy example, topic 1 may contain words and phrases like - 'fan', 'actor', 'great acting'.

Is there other ways to do this clustering? Do I need to consider the ordinal rating scale while clustering? How can I take that into account?

Answer (score 1):

Word embeddings might be useful. [Here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) is a recent, relevant Stanford project.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how sophisticated you wish the handling of the text to be. If just matching single words (1-grams) were sufficient then:

- remove stop words
- possibly do stemming or other text preprocessing
- apply a naive bayes classification algorithm  Options are here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier

However you may also wish to do a better job with phrases / related words. In that case there is plenty of research - and implementations - to help you. Ngrams is a relatively simple approach, but more advanced methods that understand the semantics of the language have better statistical performance.